# Questions about javascript alert and sendRedirect

Tags: javascript, jsp

Hi I'm a beginner in Javascript.

In the middle of a JSP source,
I want to go to another site using JavaScript's alert, response.sendRedirect.

but when I go to another site, the alert does not appear.
I can not find the cause of the above problem.

For example, I did this.

```
<%
if(boolean){
~
}
else{%>
<script> alert("alert~~!"); </script>
<%response.sendRedirect("~.jsp");
}
%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write location.href instead of response.sendRedirect
The redirect tells the client (browser) to "go back to the next address" after the server has finished processing, so the client does not parse the html sent with it ... and immediately sends a new request to the server . So your code do not take an alert.

This is the modified code.

```
<%
if( boolean){
~
}
else{%>
<script> alert("alert~~!");
location.href="xxx.jsp";
</script>
<% } %>
```